# pub get failed: Because flutter_google_places >=0.2.5 depends on rxdart ^0.24.0 on rxdart ^0.23.1,

Tags: flutter, dart, google-places

I am trying to build a flutter application and want to use flutter_google_places dependency in it but it is showing me this following error:

```
Because flutter_google_places >=0.2.5 depends on rxdart ^0.24.0 and flutter_google_places >=0.2.4 <0.2.5 depends on rxdart ^0.23.1, flutter_google_places >=0.2.4 requires rxdart ^0.23.1 or ^0.24.0.
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: what is `pubspec.yaml` dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You can either upgrade the `rxDart` package.

`rxdart: ^0.25.0`

Or, Downgrade the `flutter_google_places` package to 0.2.4.

`flutter_google_places: ^0.2.4`